# Excel - Photovoltaic - converting hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem that I would like to solve. I got data in excel, which are
[in this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egU1p.png), basically I have number of hours from 0 to 8760 in a column in excel, which represent the whole year. And in another column I have "Power from PV" which corresponds to how much power does photovoltaic system produce in that specific hour. I would like to convert these hours to months, so I could make a graph of monthly production of power in a whole year. Is there some sensible way to do this in excel?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: 7500? there are 8760 hours in a year.

Answer (score 1):

You need three things:

- You need to know that 1 equals 1 day, so if you want to convert hours into date related information, you need to divide it by 24.
- There is a function, called `Date()`, which gives the date, based on year, month and day, like `=DATE(2022,1,1)`.
- There is a function, called `Month()`, which gives the month number of a date.

So, in summary, you need something like:

```
=MONTH(DATE(2022,1,1) + A3 / 24)
```

Once you have this in a new helper column, you can start using the `Subtotals` basic Excel feature.